# How to create simplest directory watcher for a new file creation in python using inotify Linux kernel subsystem?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems, inotify, subsystem

I want to monitor a directory for new file creation in that directory. I found few project in python which are working on top of `inotify` subsystem like [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify), [PyInotify](https://github.com/dsoprea/PyInotify) and [fsmonitor](https://github.com/shaurz/fsmonitor).

I dont want to use these modules because I want to learn by creating something small subset which can only catch newly created file on Linux.

Comment: Not wanting to use an existing module is just weird. If you want to learn `inotify` by itself, maybe don't use Python.

Comment: I want to use these calls in python

Comment: Then look at how one of those modules does it, and reimplement it (poorly)

Answer (score 1):

If you are particular on using Python, you will have to call(use) a Python library which provides C bindings of the kernel's native inotify C library. This sort of inhibits productive learning. Besides that, if the bindings are not well written, you will wind up traveling the wrong road!

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty with C, [inotify man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) provides a very good example of a simple implementation. You can pick it up from there on!

Good luck!